# Value from array to array in C

Tags: c

I want to input an array, and then make 2 arrays, one contains odd elements of A and the other contains even elements. I calculated sum of all elements in those two arrays, but there was a problem like this. Can you explain for me pls?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void input(int x, int A[x]){
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        printf("A[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
}
int sum(int x, int A[x]){
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        s += A[i];
    }
    return s;
}
void OddnEven(int x, int A[x], int B[x], int C[x]){
    int m,n = 0;
    B[m] = 0;
    C[m] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        if(A[i] % 2 == 0){
            A[i] = B[m];
            ++m;
        } else {                
            A[i] = C[n];
            ++n;
        }
    } 
}
int main(){
    int x;
    printf("Enter size: "); scanf("%d", &x);
    int A[x], B[x], C[x];
    printf("Enter A: \n");
    input(x, A);
    printf("\nSum of all numbers in A:  %d", sum(x, A));
    OddnEven(x, A, B, C);
    printf("\nSum of even numbers in A: %d", sum(x, B));
    printf("\nSum of odd numbers in A: %d", sum(x, C));
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter size: 3
Enter A: 
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 2
A[2] = 3

Sum of all numbers in A:  6
Sum of even numbers in A: -1106957381
Sum of odd numbers in A: 423238244
```

Comment: Note that the statement `int m,n = 0;` will only initialise `n` to `0` and `m` will be remain uninitialised. The value of `m` is indeterminate and you should not use it before initialising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen because you are doing two wrong things in here

1st one is initiating arrays that have length x for B and C. But you don't update the values of that B and C from array A, instead of that, you are updating A from B and C. but B and C already have some garbage values. so when you add the values of A and B it adds garbage values, that is why you are getting these wrong values

2nd thing is, even if you put the values of A to B and C according to odd and even, you don't update all the values in B and C. Some indexes may update some are not, for that you need to initialize all the values of B and C something known value first (for example -1). then you can add all the values of B and C if the value is not equal to -1

You should not get -1 if you are using -1 to fill the array A, use something that you doesn't use to fill the array A

```
void OddnEven(int x, int A[x], int B[x], int C[x]){
   
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        B[i] = -1
        C[i] = -1
        if(A[i] % 2 == 0){
            B[i] = A[i];
        } else {                
            C[i] = A[i];
        }
    } 
}

int sum(int x, int A[x]){
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        if (A[i] != -1) {
          s += A[i];
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Problems in your code:

- In `OddnEven()` function, the statement `int m,n = 0;` will only initialise `n` to `0` and `m` will be remain uninitialised and it is using variable `m` before initialising. The value of `m` is indeterminate and if you use it before initialising, it will lead to undefined behaviour. Instead, you should do `int m = 0,n = 0;`
- In `OddnEven()` function, you are modifying the input array - `A[i] = B[m];`. It should be `B[m] = A[i];`. Same in else part of `if` block. May you should `const` modifier with the parameter `int A[x]`, so that compiler flag these kind of issues.
- In `sum()` function, you are adding all elements up to `x` and, due to this, your program end up accessing the array elements whose value is indeterminate. So, you should ensure that after filling up `even` numbers in array `B` and `odd` numbers in array `C`, rest of the elements of array `B` and `C` should be assigned `0`. Or keep the record of number of `even` and `odd` elements in array `B` and `C` respectively.
- In `main()` function, you should validate the user input `size` by adding upper and lower bounds check. Note that, array `A`, `B` and `C` are Variable Length Array (VLA). May you should try giving input size like a negative number or a huge positive number and check the program behaviour. Better to use some fixed size array like `A[1024]` and just add check whether the user input is `> 0` and `< 1024`. The another advantage of using fixed size array is you can initialise it like this `int A[1024] = {0};`, which is not possible in case of VLA. If it's a need to have value of all elements of a VLA `0` before using it then you have to explicitly assign `0` to all elements of a VLA.
- It is possible that sum of `even` numbers or `odd` numbers may overflow. You should check it and appropriately handle this situation.

Making the minimal required changes in your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int x, int A[x]){
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        printf("A[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
}

int sum(int x, const int A[x]){
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        s += A[i];
    }
    return s;
}

void OddnEven(int x, const int A[x], int B[x], int C[x]){
    int m = 0, n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        if(A[i] % 2 == 0){
            B[m++] = A[i];
        } else {                
            C[n++] = A[i];
        }
    }
}

void init_arr(int size, int *arr) {
    while (size--) {
        arr[size] = 0;
    }
}

int main(){
    int x;

    printf("Enter size [1 - 100]: "); 
    scanf("%d", &x);

    //validate input size from user, add check for upper and lower bound
    //for e.g. input size should not be less than 0 and greater than 100

    if ((x < 1) || (x > 100)) {
        printf ("Invalid input, exiting..\n");
        //may you want to add retry logic here..
        return 0;
    }

    int A[x], B[x], C[x];

    printf("Enter A: \n");
    input(x, A);

    init_arr(x, B);
    init_arr(x, C);

    OddnEven(x, A, B, C);

    printf("Sum of all numbers in A:  %d\n", sum(x, A));
    printf("Sum of even numbers in B: %d\n", sum(x, B));
    printf("Sum of odd numbers in C: %d\n", sum(x, C));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter size [1 - 100]: 5
Enter A: 
A[0] = 10
A[1] = 15
A[2] = 20
A[3] = 25
A[4] = 30
Sum of all numbers in A:  100
Sum of even numbers in B: 60
Sum of odd numbers in C: 40
```

Leaving it up to you to try following:

- Keeping record of number of `even` and `odd` elements in array `B` and `C` and in the sum function pass that as `size` to avoid the unnecessary loop iteration.
- Check the overflow in `sum()` function and appropriately handle it.
- At the time of taking input from user in array `A` identify whether the input number is `even` or `odd`, that way you have total number of `even` and `odd` elements in array `A` just after input from user. Declare `B` and `C` of type `int *` i.e. `int` pointer and allocate memory dynamically to them based on the `even` and `odd` number count. Make the other required changes in the program.
- May you want to try with fixed size array as well once, like `A[100], B[100] and C[100]`. Initialise them like this `int A[100] = {0}, B[100] = {0}, C[100] = {0};`. Do other required changes in the program like keeping track of `even` and `odd` elements etc.

Comment: That about covers it all. Nicely done.

Comment: In the end, `C[]`, the odd array,  can contain many even elements of 0. Otherwise fairly complete.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica`C[]` is not odd array, it is an array of integers which is supposed to contain the odd elements of array `A` :).

Answer (score 1):

Consider making a support function that test for even/odd count.

```
int OddCount(int x, const int A[x]) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if (A[i] % 2) count++;
  }
  return count;
}

// Fix initialization.
void OddnEven(int x, const int A[x], int B[x], int C[x]) {
  // int m,n = 0; // Only sets n
  int m = 0,n = 0;
  ...
}

int main(){
  int x;
  printf("Enter size: "); scanf("%d", &x);
  int A[x];  // Only A
  printf("Enter A: \n");
  input(x, A);
  printf("\nSum of all numbers in A:  %d", sum(x, A));

  int odds = OddCount(x, A);
  int evens = x - odds;
  B[evens ? evens : 1] = 0; // Insure arrays have at least size 1 to prevent UB
  C[odds ? odds : 1] = 0;

  OddnEven(x, A, B, C);
  printf("\nSum of even numbers in A: %d", sum(evens, B));  // do not use x
  printf("\nSum of odd numbers in A: %d", sum(odds, C));
}
```